# find delimiter in split string function

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I want to use whitespace as a delimiter in a split function call, but there are certain words that I want to enter into a single cell array; such as `ma kore`.

For example:

```
String str =  "azx cd ma kore cfg ma kore dfgh";
```

And after the function split call with some delimiter the output should look like this:

```
str[0] = "azx"  
str[1] = "cd"   
str[2] = "ma kore"  
str[3] = "cfg"  
str[4] = "ma kore"  
str[5] = "dfgh"
```

I need to find a delimiter (or regex pattern) to use in the split function. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: for this simple case you could use lookarounds `(?<!ma) (?!kore)`, but this is gonna get ugly if you have more of these (this will even choke on `ma` and `kore` individually without the other). it's probably better to split at a space and then wwalk through the array and recombine certain strings

Comment: @m.buettner - consider input like `abc ma def ghi kore jkl` - your pattern would not work, right?

Comment: @Ωmega that is what I mentioned in the parentheses. ;)

Comment: @m.buettner - they wouldn't be individual matches, but `abc`, `ma def`, `ghi kore`, `jkl`.

Comment: maybe my wording was a bit awkward, but this is exactly what I meant ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(ma kore|\S+)(?:$|(?=\s))
```

and find all matches/occurrences.

Comment: @m.buettner - OP wants whitespace delimiter and `\b` would work differently with string containing `+-/$%#` and other special characters

Comment: @m.buettner - Ooops, yes `)` was missing. I fixed that. Next time, my friend, please feel free to edit my post when you see some typo like this :) Thanks.